# How to make a function in Node JS run only once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a simple tictactoe terminal game in JS. I use the variable named player1Input to get user prompt. If the prompt is not equal to "X", I call the function  again to make sure the user input the right input. If I enter the wrong input multiple times, the function (player1Game) ends up being called multiple times instead of once. How do I get it to just be called once.  I put a snippet of my code at the bottom.I commented the part of the code that makes the function run twice

```
function player1Game () {
    let player1Input = prompt(`${player1Name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + player1Name.slice(1) } please enter \"x\": `);
    //Create an error that responds if player 1 does not type x
    if (player1Input !== "x") {
        console.log("Please make sure you type in x")
        player1Game(); 
       //the function runs multiple times here instead of once.
       // How do I get it to run only once.
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you show more code context here?  And, what exactly do you want to NOT run when what condition occurs.  Please be more specific than your current question.  Good clear questions with full context usually get fast and accurate answers, but this question is not yet that complete.

Comment: I just updated the code and the question. Please let me know if it is clearer.

Comment: Well, YOUR code is specifically calling `player1Game()` again every time the input does not meet the "x" requirement.  So, that's why it's executing multiple times.  I assume you don't actually want the function to only run once.  Please clarify by showing more code and describing in more detail what should not run more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still aren't showing the whole context here, but perhaps you just need to `return` after you call it again so that the rest of the function doesn't execute when the function doesn't meet the input requirements:

```
function player1Game () {
    let player1Input = prompt(`${player1Name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + player1Name.slice(1) } please enter \"x\": `);
    //Create an error that responds if player 1 does not type x
    if (player1Input !== "x") {
        console.log("Please make sure you type in x")
        player1Game(); 
        // return so it doesn't execute any more of the function
        return;          
    }
    // code here will only get called if the `player1Input` 
    // meets the above critera

    // Rest of your code here...
}
```

Or, you could use an `if/else`:

```
function player1Game () {
    let player1Input = prompt(`${player1Name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + player1Name.slice(1) } please enter \"x\": `);
    //Create an error that responds if player 1 does not type x
    if (player1Input !== "x") {
        console.log("Please make sure you type in x")
        player1Game(); 
    } else {
        // code here will only get called if the `player1Input` 
        // meets the above critera

        // Rest of your code here...
    }
}
```

FYI, there's nothing special here.  This is just normal function control flow in Javascript.  If you want no more of the function to execution then insert a `return` statement.  Or protect branches of code with an `if/else` so a condition will control what code executes.

Comment: the second solution actually answers my question thank you! I was missing an else statement. Thank you !